# Automating through shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hive, scheduled-tasks

I have a script to validate a hive table.
How can I automate this validation process using shell script such that the script runs periodically? 
Please help me with some suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered creating a `cron` job?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Comment: please google first, what you want to do before posting question on SO. Post If you dont find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check for the watch and at commands.

Example to execute every 100 seconds:

watch --interval=100 test.sh args

Its used to run at specified time:

at -f test.sh -v 10:25

2) use the crontab

see the examples here: https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/#

Comment: is there anyway i can stop the process because it is running continuously? or how can i make it work in background?

Comment: Yes, watch runs continuously and refresh the result. Ctrl-C stop the process. you do the background process: watch --interval=3 echo test >> test.log 2>&1 &, still it refreshes the previous results. I think you prefer to use: while true; do sleep 10; script.sh >>script_output.txt; done &; It will run continuously and output redirects. to stop the process, you can use kill -9 <background_process_id>